# How to use quote and unquote to more faithfully translate The Reasoned Schemer into Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, quote, minikanren

(Details of my miniKanren in Racket setup appear at the bottom[1].)

The way quotes and unquotes work in The Reasoned Schemer appears not to match the way they work in Racket. For instance, verse 2 of chapter 2 suggests[2] the following function definition:

```
(run #f
     (r )
     (fresh (y x )
            (== '(,x ,y) r )))
```

If I evaluate that, I get `'((,x ,y))`. If instead I rewrite it as this:

```
(run #f
     (r )
     (fresh (y x )
            (== (list x y) r)))
```

I get the expected result, `'((_.0 _.1))`.

This might seem like a minor problem, but in many cases the required translation is extremely verbose. For instance, in exercise 45 of chapter 3 (page 34), the book provides, roughly[3] the following definition:

```
(run 5 (r)
     (fresh (w x y z)
            (loto (('g 'g) ('e w) (x y) . z))
            (== (w (x y) z) r)))
```

In order to get the results they get, I had to rewrite it like this:

```
(run 5 (r)
     (fresh (w x y z)
            (loto (cons '(g g)
                        (cons (list 'e w)
                              (cons (list x y)
                                    z))))
            (== (list w (list x y) z)
                r)))
```

[1] As described [here](https://www.monolune.com/using-racket-for-the-reasoned-schemer/), I ran `raco pkg install minikanren` and then defined a few missing pieces.

[2] Actually, they don't write precisely that, but if you heed the advice in the footnotes to that verse and an earlier verse, it's what you get.

[3] Modulo some implicit quoting and unquoting that I cannot deduce.

Comment: Looks like you should use [`quasiquote`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._quasiquote%29%29) instead of `quote`.

Comment: quasiquote is the one written with a backtick ( `` ` `` ) which is on the same key as tilde (`~`), not the normal tick (`'`)

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that `(cons '(g g) (cons (list 'e w) (cons (list x y) z)))` can be written as `(list* '(g g) (list 'e w) (list x y) z)`.

Comment: @PetSerAl If z is a proper list, that is true. That section of the book, though, delves into the problems associated with improper lists.

Comment: @JeffreyBenjaminBrown Can you show example when this is not true? Assuming `cons` and `list*` have their normal definitions, AFAIK, `(list* a b c d e)` should be the same as `(cons a (cons b (cons c (cons d e))))`. https://www.ideone.com/rxqmB5

Comment: @PetSerAl Consider a simpler example: `(list 1 3)` = `(1 3)`, while `(cons 1 3)` = `(1 . 3)`. The first is a proper list, the cdr of which is `(3)`. The second is an improper list; its cdr is `3` instead of `(3)`.

Comment: @JeffreyBenjaminBrown `(list 1 3)` is `(1 3)`, but `(list* 1 3)` is `(1 . 3)`.

Comment: Thanks! My bad. I didn't know about `list*` and read it as `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the backquote `` ` `` instead of the simple quote `'` you have been using.